# How to read rtfd data in .Net

Tags: windows, macos, rtf

i have one .plist file containing some RTFD data in form of Base64 encoded string. I want to read that RTFD data in the .net application. In .Net i can convert base64 to byte array easily. But, don't know how to extract files from RTFD data byte array. If i save the byte array to some file on disk and then open it in notepad, then i can see rtf data along with attached image binary stored in it. My problem is i didn't found any RTFD file format or specification to read its binary structure in windows.

I need to know, Is there any RTFD file structure specification available? OR Any other way to read RTFD directly in .net.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/RTFD. Also, you may consider saving the file in the temp directory and then browsing for it as if it were a directory.

Comment: Thanks, But as i mention in my question, is that i am reading RTFD data from plist file. So it will not create any folder, if i store that byte array content into file on disk.

Comment: Ok, according to this post [http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/129026-rtfd-binary-format-internals.html], RTFD is a directory which is configured to be displayed as a package. So, if you write this into an .rtfd entry, wouldn't it be parsed like one?

Comment: I am storing RTFD as NSData in plist. And NSData generated using RTFDFromRange method.